# No longer able to create an entity using the dev_appserver admin console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I cleared all entities from the datastore and cleared the memcache, created an entity using the API Explorer and then attempted to create another one of the same kind in the Datastore console running on localhost:

**Internal Server Error**

The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/admin_request_handler.py", line 97, in dispatch
    super(AdminRequestHandler, self).dispatch()
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/datastore_viewer.py", line 760, in get
    count=20)
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/datastore_viewer.py", line 121, in _get_entities
    query = datastore.Query(kind, _namespace=namespace)
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 1361, in __init__
    datastore_errors.BadArgumentError)
  File "/home/tom/work/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 181, in ValidateString
    raise exception('%s must not be empty.' % name)
BadArgumentError: kind must not be empty.
```

Here's the gcloud version info:

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 157.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.54
beta 2017.03.24
bq 2.0.24
core 2017.05.30
gcloud 
gsutil 4.26
```

Any hints as to what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: No idea. I recently upgraded to the Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine and don't believe I saw the problem before that. But I use the console infrequently and almost never to create entities, so the problem could have been present before the upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bug in the Datastore console.

I was able to replicate the same error on my machine. If you look at the traceback in the exception, you see (fourth from the bottom):

```
File "/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/datastore_viewer.py", line 760, in get
count=20)
```

If you look at that file from line 735, you see:

```
def get(self, entity_key_string=None):
    super(DatastoreEditRequestHandler, self).get(entity_key_string)
    if entity_key_string:
        entity_key = datastore.Key(entity_key_string)
        entity_key_name = entity_key.name()
        entity_key_id = entity_key.id()
        namespace = entity_key.namespace()
        kind = entity_key.kind()
        entities = [datastore.Get(entity_key)]
        parent_key = entity_key.parent()
        if parent_key:
            parent_key_string = _format_datastore_key(parent_key)
        else:
            parent_key_string = None
    else:
        entity_key = None
        entity_key_string = None
        entity_key_name = None
        entity_key_id = None
        namespace = self.request.get('namespace')
        kind = self.request.get('kind')
        entities, _ = _get_entities(kind,
                                    namespace,
                                    order=None,
                                    start=0,
                                    count=20)  ### line 760 #######
        ...
```

In that last line, `kind` is supposed to be string containing the model name of the model you are working with. Instead, if you follow the traceback down into that function call, you see that `kind` is an empty string. I don't think there's much you can do to fix it at this time. I'd recommend using the interactive console for now to create/edit your Datastore entities, and just use the viewer to view them. I'm sure Google will fix this with an update soon.

**Edit**: I actually found a hacky fix if you really want the Datastore console to work, but I would still recommend just using the interactive console. The hacky fix is you manually enter the `kind` variable into the URL sent by the Datastore console.

When you click "Create New Entity" and get the error you show in your question, look at the url:

```
http://localhost:8000/datastore/edit?kind=&next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fdatastore%3Fkind%3DUnique
```

You see `...:8000/datastore/edit?kind=&...`. Right there, just type in the model name. For example, let's say your model name is `User`:

```
http://localhost:8000/datastore/edit?kind=User&next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fdatastore%3Fkind%3DUnique
```

This brought me to the "Create new entity" form for class User (one of my models), and I was able to create a user with that form.

P.S. You may want to also change the model name on the very end of that url (where mine says `Unique`) to match the kind you are creating, because that model name is the kind that will be displayed after you create your new entity. So mine created a `User`, but then displayed the `Unique` entities (`Unique` is one of my model names).